# How to build cpp-templates for Cocos2d-X-3.8.1 with Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, cocos2d-x

I'm a new guy in Cocos2d-X. I download the cocos2d-x-3.8.1.zip, the newest version in official website, http://www.cocos2d-x.org/.

Extract the zip, I successfully open and build /cocos2d-x-3.8.1/build/cocos2d-win32.sln with Visual Studio2015 community.

Then I try to open cocos2d-x-3.8.1/templates/cpp-template-default/proj.win32/HelloCpp.sln, but the VS2015 tell me there are errors when load solution.

I thought VS2015 is too new for Cocos2d-x-3.8.1, so I uninstalled the VS2015, install the Visual Studio 2013 community. But the same thing happen, build/cocos2d-win32.sln is successful, /templates/HelloCpp.sln is failed.

I follow some books, it tell me to set up a template Visual Studio template with VC++ for cocos2d-x, but I wonder why it's failed when I build the cpp template.

Is VS2013/2015 to new for cocos2d-x-3.8.1 ?
Is it a must to use Visual Studio 2012 ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't just download and extract there is more to do then just that
you need to setup cocos2d-x environment variables first then run your projects
and here is a you-tube tutorial that shows you how to:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B9ObAzm6rnQ&index=3&list=PLRtjMdoYXLf4od_bOKN3WjAPr7snPXzoe

after you do all the steps in the video just open cocos2d-win32.sln and run it and it will automatically builds(takes a minute or tow) then runs.

PS: VS 2013 or 2015 both should work ... i myself using cc2d 3.8 with VS2013update5 and it all works fine.